# Unable to set HTML text into InnerHtml property

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

My application has built in ASP.NET MVC 5. Now, what I am trying to do is that application retrieves the text data from database and generate some html text. So, i can set that html text into a specific div element by assigning `innerHtml` property. But, when i try to assign that html text into that div it doesn't render. It shows html text.

[image]

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById('discussion');
    elem.innerHTML = "@Server.HtmlDecode(@discussionDiv.ToString())";
</script>
```

Is there any better way that can i use to set that html text into my dom element?

Comment: `@` automatically encodes html. Use `Html.Raw` to output raw html or use `MvcHtmlString` instead of normal `string`.

Comment: Thanks @Mathew I have tried that. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Html.Raw`

```
elem.innerHTML = '@Html.Raw(discussionDiv.ToString())';
```

Since it contains a lot of double quotes `"` i've opted to use single quotes on the value.

Comment: Thanks @scartag Its wokring